# Can't update BIOS on Dell E6530

Tags: windows-7, bios, dell-latitude

I have a problem with the video output on my E6530. It does not show anything during POST on my external screens.
As it seems this is related to A09 BIOS which is currently installed.

I wanted to upgrade to A11 BIOS and downloaded the installer from the Dell Website.

The installer launches correctly and displays the current version, the update versions and reboots the system afterwards.

Bit the BIOS version remains A09.

I have no idea where to start troubleshooting.

Any hints?

Thank you very much.

System Spec:

OS: Windows 7 x64 SP1
AV: Kaspersky Endpoint Security 8.1
UAC: Disabled, my user is in the Administrators group

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the Windows software.  I would use the alternative methods that Dell provides to update the BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaspersky seemed to block something.

After disabling it, the installer ran and after rebooting the BIOS was updated.
As it seems the installer copies the update file to the hdd, as the update itself was done on BIOS level.

I would have been nice if Kaspersky said something :(

Comment: Just some thing about this kinda updates when ever you want to update bios or some thing like that use safe mode antivirus wont run there

Comment: How is your security software suppose to know its suppose to allow the application.  Furthermore I guaratnee you the instructions told you to disable your security software.